# Starting and tracking a process from c#

Tags: c#, process

I'm running into some strange stuff, hopefully someone can shed some light here...

I have my main app, app A, and I need to launch another app (app B) from App A.   App A also needs to know when app B has exited.  The code I've been using to do this looks like this:

```
_applicationProcess.StartInfo = 
     new ProcessStartInfo { FileName = _currentExecutablePath, WorkingDirectory = dir };
_applicationProcess.Start();
```

And I subscribe to the Exited event on the Process (_applicationProcess) to detect when it finishes.

Here's the kicker though.  Both app A and app B share a library that sends a notification when a service is initialized (this is hooking up to the kinect service, as both apps are Kinect apps).

The bizarre thing is that when app B is launched using the code above, app A gets notified that the service is initialized.  Yuck!

I don't want this.  I want app B to be totally isolated from app A, yet I need to know when it has ended.

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you sure that this has nothing to do with the kinect service itself? What happens if you have app A running and start app B manually by just running the executable from a normal shell? Does A get a notification even then?

Comment: Yep checked that- if you start each app separately app A does not get notified when app B starts.

Comment: You'll need to document "sends a notification" better.